# vba type mismatch for a division between double

Tags: excel, vba

I want to perform a division between two double numbers in cell formatted as text (like 3.000) (excel 2010, VBA 7.0 version 1628).

The code:

```
Dim coeffsVal As Range
Dim val As Range
Dim reqVal As Range
Dim parameter As Range

            With ActiveSheet
                For Each reqVal In .Range("D2", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

                    Set coeffsVal = reqVal.Offset(, -1)
                    Set val = reqVal.Offset(, -2)
                    Set parameter = reqVal.Offset(, -3)                        

                    coeffsVal.value = reqVal.value / val.value 
                        End If
```

All the ranges you see actually refer to single cells, and the values are well fetched.
I don't know why when I try to perform

```
                        coeffsVal.value = reqVal.value / val.value
```

It returns me a type mismatch error.
I have also tried with

```
coeffsVal.value = CDec(reqVal.value) / CDec(val.value)
```

and

```
coeffsVal.value = CDbl(reqVal.value) / CDbl(val.value)
```

with same result.
I tried to spy the value of the vars and I have:

```
> val: 1.000 (written as text I suppose) 
> reqVal: 3 (no matter if I insert it as 3 or 3.000)
```

I tried also to set or not reqVal as a NumberFormat= "0.000", with same unsuccess.

Moreover, I tried the same exact code on another pc (Excel 2010 VBA 7.0 version 1640) and works nicely.
Un update of the excel version is not viable.

Comment: Did you try to set type as **Long** @Andrea Giordano ?

Comment: If I try to do:
Dim valTMP as Long and then valTMP = val.value I obtain a Type incompatible error on it

Comment: Shouldn't this `.Range("D2", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` be this: `.Range("D2", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, the problem seemed related to the fact that 1.000 is not parsed like a number, while 1,000 does.

So, before the calculation, I have replaced the dot with a comma and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try with *Val*:

```
coeffsVal.value = Val(reqVal.value) / Val(val.value)

coeffsVal.value = IIf(IsNumeric(reqVal.value) And IsNumeric(val.value), Val("" & reqVal.value)/IIf(Val("0" & val.value) <> 0, Val("0" & val.value), 1), 0)
```

Comment: Then (some of) your values are not numbers. Try with some extended test - see edited answer, please.